# Confirmation of grammar/usage "The parents"

Tags: grammar

I came across this sentence in Duolingo. 'The parents like the cheese.' which sounds wrong to me... Shouldn't it be accompanied by a pronoun My/Your/Everyone?.

I reported it as a problem... I would like to know if I'm right/wrong.

It seems acceptable in the context of biology. If you were talking about bacteria.

Comment: It would also be acceptable in the context of a school fundraising dinner.  But I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: Can you give a full sentence alternative? Also, ask on Duolingo, they have lots of people thinking about exactly your kinds of problems with their sentences.

Comment: The full sentence was 'The parents like the cheese.' I was expecting  something like 'My parents like the cheese', or 'All the parents like the cheese' or ''The parents liked the cheese'. I think it just sounds strange in a simple sentence with no context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your point: in most cases, the word *parents* will be preceded by a possessive pronoun. However, there are still plenty of cases in which it will be preceded by *the*. It isn't even unusual.

> At Hypatia's birthday party, cheese is brought in. The children hate the cheese, but the parents like the cheese.